# Property with blank node as range

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs, blank-nodes

When I define property in ontology, how would I define that range of this property is a "blank" node? For example I want to define property `hasPhoneNumber` with domain `Person`. Than I know that person can have more than one phone numbers, so instance of `Person` will have blank node attached to `hasPhoneNumber` property and then phone numbers attached to this blank node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't do this. Blank nodes are just another type of resource.  Blank nodes act as existential variables in RDF;  use of a blank node in a graph says that *some* resource exists and stands in certain relationships to other.  For instance, the graph (with no blank nodes):

```
:x :hasPhoneNumber :phoneNumberList .
:phoneNumbeList rdf:value "phone number 1", "phone number 2" .
```

*entails* the following graph (with blank nodes):

```
:x :hasPhoneNumber [ rdf:value "phone number 1", "phone number 2" ] .
```

For more about this treatment, see [1.5. Blank Nodes as Existential Variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-mt/#unlabel) from the W3C recommendation, [RDF Semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-mt/).

At the RDF and RDFS level, (where you'd be defining domains and ranges of properties) to distinguish whether a resource is a URI resource or a blank node.  It's not really clear what it would *mean* either, if you could.   By saying that

```
:p rdfs:domain :C ;
   rdfs:range  :D .
```

what you're saying is that any time you see a use of `:p`, e.g.,

```
:a :p :b .
```

that you can add the following triples to the graph:

```
:a rdf:type :C .
:b rdf:type :D .
```

Notice since `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range` are about adding more triples to the graph, it doesn't really matter whether the subject and object of a triple using `:p` (`:a` and `:b` in this case) are blank nodes or URI nodes.

If you want to have more than one phone number for a person, you could just use multiple triples, and have something like:

```
:p :hasPhoneNumber :phoneNumber1 , :phoneNumber2, :phoneNumber3 .
```

which is the three triples:

```
:p :hasPhoneNumber :phoneNumber1 .
:p :hasPhoneNumber :phoneNumber2 .
:p :hasPhoneNumber :phoneNumber3 .
```

Alternatively, if you want to model that a person can have some collection of phone numbers, you might use an RDF container.  E.g., with an `rdf:List`:

```
:p :hasPhoneNumber ( :phoneNumber1 :phoneNumber2 :phoneNumber3 ) .
```

which can be written in full as

```
:p :hasPhoneNumber [ rdf:first :phoneNumber1 ;
                     rdf:rest [ rdf:first :phoneNumber2 ;
                                rdf:rest [ rdf:first :phoneNumber3 ;
                                           rdf:rest  rdf:nil ] ] ] .
```